# Trouble booting Snappy on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: boot, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu Core Snappy (`ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-raspi2.img`) on a miniSD card following the [official instructions1]. Everything went fine with no error and the miniSD has 3 partitions now.

But when booting the Raspberry Pi 2 with this miniSD, I have the kernel boot messages flying on the screen and then nothing. The HDMI screen turns blue and displays "no signal".

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the USB2miniUSB cable and this time, the computer booted completely... Strange but it seems the cable I was using was of too low quality and not supplying enough power.

Comment: Don't ask questions in your answer.  Yes, it makes perfect sense, since not all cables are of the same quality capable of providing the power needed to run the RPi.  Same goes for power adapters as well (not just the cables)